How to set up warp::serve to use tls in Rust
Warp Crate issue.
So I'm having some issues setting up my server using warp. How do we set up the server using warp to be tls? Am I doing it right?
    warp::serve(routes)
    .tls()
    .cert_path(cert_path)
    .key_path(key_path)
    .run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 443))
    .await;

Warp version:
warp = {version = "0.3", features = ["tls"]}
I tried changing .cert_path to .cert(cert_path) and got runtime errors:
    warp::serve(routes)
    .tls()
    .cert(cert_path)
    .key(key_path)
    .run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 443))
    .await;

errors:7/src/server.rs:550:27: error binding to 0.0.0.0:443: Identity PEM is missing a private key such as RSA, ECC or PKCS8
I am using the latest version of Warp, which right now, is 0.3.7 . Can someone walk me through how to set up a server that uses https in the newest warp verison? In the first code block, the issue is when I went to open up my website using https:// nothing showed up.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78796093/warp-crate-error-trying-to-configure-server-in-rust-for-https-but-identity-pe
